# How to redirect a nextjs app hosted on Heroku from http to https?

Tags: redirect, heroku, https, next.js

I have a nextjs app hosted on Heroku. The app doesn't have a custom server, and visiting the https URL directly works fine.

However, if users visit the http URL directly, I'd like to redirect them to the https page.

What's the best way to achieve this these days?

There is a very hacky solution mentioned [here](https://spectrum.chat/thread/94b86791-3c78-49ce-8405-4c65dd2f5adc?m=MTU2MjIxNjEwNTg3Mg==), but I have the feeling that there is a better solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't use nginx reverse proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Edge addon in Heroku` which places a CloudFront CDN in front of your app which can handles the redirection. This enforces HTTPS i.e. Edge automatically redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Source:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an addon, you can use `heroku-community/nginx` buildpack with a custom nginx configuration that forces HTTPS with:

```
http {
  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {

      <% if ENV['NGINX_SKIP_HTTPS_PROXY'] == 'true' %>
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
      <% end %>

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #next serve listens here and receives nginx requests
    }
  }
}
```

You can find the full configuration details in [this post](https://pulkitgoyal.in/ssl-nextjs-deployment-on-heroku).